# Sharepoint : AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Delegation blob grant is malformed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

When trying to get the access_token using the refresh_token for my SharePoint site using WebRequest i get the following error "AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Delegation blob grant is malformed".

I am making a POST call with the following parameters
1.grant_type
2.refresh_token
3.client_id
4.client_secret
5.resource

Wanted to check if there is something missing.